# Defining a new version of \addcontentsline fails with hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

The example below defines a new version of `\addcontentsline` which does not show `\thepage`. Unfortunately, the compilation fails when `hyperref` is introduced. I have no clue why?

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\addcontentslinepart#1#2#3{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
       \addcontentslinepart{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
\@endpart}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Title}
\chapter{Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\contentsline` expects 4 arguments when hyperref is loaded. Check the toc to see how it should look.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ohohoh, thank you! Completely overlooked that aspect. You can probably turn this into an answer.

Comment: @pluton You should redefine `\@part` ***before*** loading `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg yes you are right. Then hyperref will do the job. Ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer to your problem (which at least requires redefining `\@part` before loading `hyperref`; there's a much simpler way: redefine `\l@part` to ignore its second argument.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@part{#2}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title}
\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are loading `titletoc`, the macro to patch is `\ttl@savel@part`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\ttl@savel@part{#2}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Title}
\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost there but fails when `titletoc` is used. I have to investigate why. The command is probably redefined there.

Comment: @pluton Of course it will fail, but if you don't give essential information in the MWE, we can't know you're using it.

Comment: Well, I am investigating at the same time on the problem that I am facing which is more complicated than the provided MWE and I just noticed that `titletoc` was messing around.

Comment: @pluton I added the corresponding workaround

Comment: Great thanks. That's what I was about to isolate in `titletoc.sty`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\addcontentslinepart#1#2#3{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}{\@currentHref}}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
       \addcontentslinepart{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
\@endpart}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Title}
\chapter{Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution removes the bookmark at the part level. This is unclear why.